# Can we use bootstrap to estimate Mode of the population?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, bootstrap, resampling, mode

I have known that bootstrapping can be used to estimate the population mean, Is it valid if we estimate the population mode too? Further, can we estimate any population parameter with the help of bootstrapping, or there any limitation for some parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap *is not* used to estimate mean. It [can be used](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191301/how-to-estimate-population-mean-by-bootstrap-sampling) to estimate the *uncertainty* of the estimate for mean. You can use it in same way to estimate the uncertainty around any statistic, by following the same procedure: sampling with replacement from the data and evaluating the statistic on the sample, to eventually learn the distribution of the estimates by repeating this procedure many times.